# How does using external scripts in html reduce the download time for a web page

Tags: html, http

I know that using external files can reduce download time for browsers, is this because the lines of code are shorter? But if this was the case wouldn't the number of HTTP connections required to download an external script in html be higher and therefore cause it to download slower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using external .js files does reduce the amount of time required for the ***.html file*** to download because the JavaScript is removed from it. **However, this does not necessarily mean that the total time to initially process the page is reduced.**

Here are some things to take into account:

- If the references to the external script files are placed near the
  end of the HTML `<body>`, the HTML content can be parsed, without
  interruption, and a visible UI can be seen quicker than if the user
  agent had to process the JavaScript first.
- If the external references point to well-known and used resources
  from popular Content Delivery Networks (CDNs), like JQuery, then it's
  possible the user may already have a cached copy of this resource
  stored locally and so, the browser won't need to actually download
  the file again.

On the contrary side....

- If the scripts are not files that the user has already downloaded,
  then the total time to download the page vs. if the scripts were
  embedded inside the page will be the same.
- Even if the scripts are separated into their own files, if the
  scripts are not at the bottom of the HTML, the page may appear to
  have a longer load time because the UI may not be visible and/or
  responsive right away.
- Browsers/Operating Systems usually put a "cap" on the amount of
  simultaneous HTTP requests that can be made at any given time. As
  such, it is often recommended to combine external .js files (where
  appropriate) to reduce the amount of HTTP requests a page has to
  make.  Keep in mind that every image, every CSS file, every `iframe` source, every .js file, every AJAX call all amount to more requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean cdn with external files, the answer is caching. The user most likely visited another page, pointing to the resource before and still knows about it. Therefore it does not need to load the resource anymore, which is faster.

Comment: what do you mean by 'caching' i know that a cache is a temporary storage but how does caching speed it up?

Comment: Lets say you load jquery from [there](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js) - the browser by default caches the file as long as defined by the cdn serving webserver. If another page has loaded this file before, your browser knows it already.